# My submenu will only apear if i refresh my page?

Tags: html, css, hover, submenu

I'm working on a project for school and the teacher told me that if I hover a certain image a submenu needs to appear. I have some code and it works but only if i refresh my browser. I don't know why.

I also think i should make an  element in my HTML and put content in it in my css but i tried that and it doesn't work either. Below is my HTML code:

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="structural">De Fonduepot</h1>
        <section class="clearfix">
            <h2 class="structural">Kop</h2>
            <img src="images/kop.png" alt="afbeelding waar twee fonduepotten
                                      opstaan en de naam van het resaurant" />
            <img src="images/menu.jpg" alt="menu icoon voor mobiel surfen" />
            <ul id="mobilemenu">
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="reserveren.html">Reserveren</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <nav>
            <h2 class="structural">Menu</h2>
            <ul id="mainmenu">
                              <li><a href="home.html" id="selected">Home</a></li>
                              <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                              <li><a href="reserveren.html">Reserveren</a></li>
                              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
#mobilemenu {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 1%;
  top: 76%;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  display: none;
}

#mobilemenu li a {
  line-height: 3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 0.1rem solid #381402;
  color: #ac0909;
  background-color: #dabd8b;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#mobilemenu li a:hover {
  color: #dabd8b;
  background-color: #ac0909;
}

header section {
  background-image: url("../images/zand.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0.25rem solid #f3deba;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

header img:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 2%;
}

header img:last-of-type {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  width: 13%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0.25rem solid #f3deba;
}

header img:last-of-type:hover + #mobilemenu {
  display: block;
}

#mobilemenu:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I think its a little strange that your element with display:none needs to be hovered on for it to appear. if you want the menu to appear when the user hovers on clearfix, try .clearfix:hover > #mobilemenu{ display:block; }

Comment: that's a good trick but I only need the submenu to appear if I hover the image, not the hole section

Comment: .wrapper:hover > .clearfix > #mobilemenu{display:block}

Comment: I really think you don't understand me, my submenu only needs to appear if i hover above the image: images/menu.jpg, if i do it like you say, it will appear also if i hover above the image: images/kop.png

Comment: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/pwWqL/1/ 
I don't see the problem. It only appears if the second image is hovered over

Comment: it seems correct but if i try this code in my browser it wil only appear if refresh and then hover the image, I need it to appear without refreshing

Comment: I think its a bug in Chrome or something, because if I open the same project in internet explorer, i works fine

Comment: @user3646130 I would suggest validating your code here: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: It has passed, but the problem is when i resize my screen and then try to hover above the image, the menu won't come up untill i refresh my page

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing in IE be sure to close all tags correctly:

```
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
```

Must be

```
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: that </li> dissapeared when I pasted this code, sorry for that

Comment: which browser are you testing.. i just used a fiddle and seems to work as you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/gomflo/BVSZt/

Comment: yeah but if you resize the page and then try again it doesn't work until you refresh your page